# how to deploy a page with XML in Visual Studio that having Friendly Url?

Tags: deployment, xslt

how to deploy a page with XML in  Visual Studio that having Friendly Url?

Does anyone knows how can I do that?

example what not have Friendly Url

```
<File Path="Home.aspx" Url="Home.aspx" Type="GhostableInLibrary" Level="Published" ReplaceContent="TRUE" IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="TRUE">
  <Property Name="Title" Value="Home" />
  <Property Name="Comments" Value="Página de inicio" />
  <Property Name="PublishingPageLayout" Value="~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/pagelayout.aspx, Diseño de página" />
  <Property Name="ContentType" Value="Diseño de página" />
</File>
```

Comment: What do you mean by url friendly?

Comment: instead of **http://contoso.com/development/pages/sharepoint.aspx** best **http://contoso.com/development/sharepoint**

Comment: That is called a Friendly Url :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can accomplish this declaratively via CAML within an elements.xml file. However, if you are developing for SharePoint 2013 you may want to look into [managed navigation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn194311.aspx#section1), specifically the friendly URLs functionality:

> "Friendly URLs are URLs that correspond to a term in the navigation term set, and that provide a shorter, more meaningful URL to a page. This makes the URL more useful to visitors to your site, and also improves search engine optimization (SEO) for your site. For example, the URL http://www.contoso.com/products/household/vacuum-cleaner is more meaningful to both users and search engines than the URL http://www.contoso.com/Products/Inventory/Pages/productViewer.aspx?productID=115&name=vacuum%20cleaner&CID=34q327234ef. By default, when you create a new page, a new navigation term is created, and a corresponding friendly URL is created for the page. You can use a single friendly URL to point to a single page. You can also have multiple friendly URLs that point to the same page, such as a category page. For example, if you use cross-site publishing to display content from a knowledge base, you can have separate friendly URLs for /kb/manuals, /kb/troubleshooting-guides, and /kb/product-specs that all point to the same category page, Category-KB-Articles.aspx. You do not have to use cross-site publishing to use multiple friendly URLs that point to the same page."

If, on the other hand, you are developing for SharePoint 2010, check out [this](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/4-ways-short-urls-sharepoint-server-2010/) blog post by SharePoint MVP [Waldek Mastykarz](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/). He discusses a few options for getting friendly URLs working in SharePoint 2010.

Answer (score 0):

You can use meta data [managed navigation](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/office365-sharepoint-online-enterprise-help/enable-managed-navigation-for-a-site-in-sharepoint-HA104122539.aspx)